# Filling in a form

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

Trying to get search results on the IMDb website. Code is the following:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.imdb.com");
    HtmlInput input1 = page1.getElementByName("q");
    input1.setValueAttribute("Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles");

    HtmlSubmitInput submit = page1.getElementByName("navbar-submit-button");

    page1 = submit.click();

    System.out.println(page1.asText());

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

The output I get is:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException:
>   elementName=[*] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[navbar-find]     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getElementByName(HtmlPage.java:1747)
>     at main.Main.main(Main.java:37) Java Result: 1

The id from the submit button is: navbar-submit-button.

The source code is this:

```
<button id="navbar-submit-button" class="primary btn" type="submit"><div class="magnifyingglass navbarSprite"></div></button>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want getElementByID for this case, not name.

Comment: Thank you for you respond. I tried that, but then I need to use a DomElement for the submit variable and you cannot use the click function in a DomElement, I thought.

Answer (score 2):

There are two important situations in your example:

1 - You need an element named `q` because of the line:

`HtmlInput input1 = page1.getElementByName("q");`

2 - You have an element with `id="navbar-submit-button"`, so you have to use getElementById:

```
HtmlSubmitInput submit = page1.getElementById("navbar-submit-button");
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your quick respond!
Second, I tried the part with getElementById, but then the submit variable needs to be a DomElement, which doesn't has a click function. Would you have a solution for that? Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunaly no, but i'm going to search for something

Comment: Couldn't find it, maybe that way it is not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

The way it worked for me, was to use XPath. This was I could just choose the id. Went great. Thanks for your help.